# How to import pairwise function from itertools? Do I need to update itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a problem with updating itertools package, so that the pairwise function is available.

I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'pairwise'

Additionally, this command:

```
print(itertools.__version__)
```

returns:

> AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute '**version**'

and I do not know why.

How to check the version of `itertools` that I have? And how to update this package so I can have the pairwise function?

I tried to update the `itertools` by myself but I failed.

I update python to 3.11. When I type in termnal:

> python3.11 --version

I get:

> Python 3.11.0

Comment: You don't update individual Python standard library modules; you update Python. https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: [New in version 3.10](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)

Comment: @KlasŠ. so "New in version 3.10." is related to python not itertools?

Comment: @KlasŠ. and why "print(itertools.__version__)" command does not work?

Comment: @hodowcanietoperzy, just like **kaya3** said, it's standard library, which is bundled with Python.

Comment: Having no dedicated version for stdlib module is what I would expect =)

Comment: @KlasŠ. I edited the post (I have python 3.11) and I still do not have pairwise function. Can you help?

Comment: You probably have multiple Python versions installed. Are you sure you're running your script with 3.11?

Comment: @CrazyChucky I think so. In terminal I type python3.11 and then import itertools.pairwise. And I have the same error "No module named 'itertools.pairwise'; 'itertools' is not a package"

Comment: That's because `import itertools.pairwise` is not the correct way to import a name from a module. Whatever code you wrote which gave you *"AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'pairwise'"* in the earlier Python version, is what you should write in the updated Python version.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to import a function as if it was a package:

```
 $ python3.11 -c 'import itertools.pairwise'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'itertools.pairwise'; 'itertools' is not a package
```

This is how it's done

```
from itertools import pairwise
pairwise(...)
# OR
import itertools
itertools.pairwise(...)
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like in my version of python, thats give that same error, itertools doesnt have the pairwise function any more. To get my code running I change *from itertools import pairwise* to **from more_itertools import pairwise**

```
Python 3.9.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, May 27 2022, 16:56:21) 
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import itertools
>>> dir(itertools)
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_grouper', '_tee', '_tee_dataobject', 'accumulate', 'chain', 'combinations', 'combinations_with_replacement', 'compress', 'count', 'cycle', 'dropwhile', 'filterfalse', 'groupby', 'islice', 'permutations', 'product', 'repeat', 'starmap', 'takewhile', 'tee', 'zip_longest']
```

Comment: Doesn't have it *yet*, actually. It was added in 3.10. The asker clarified that they have 3.11, so your error comes from a different source.